# Fishpig Wordpress Extension for Magento Category Hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, hierarchy, fishpig

I'm working on a Magento site which is using the Fishpig Wordpress Extension.  We have the Categories widget displaying in the left sidebar & it is set to show hierarchy.

[image]

It is working two levels deep (i.e. ul & li's with `.level0` & `.level1`), but is not showing categories 3 levels deep i.e. `level2`

I've tested this on a basic wordpress installation and I can get it to display categories 3 levels down but I can't get it to work on Magento with the fishpig WordPress integration.  I have assigned posts to all the sub categories.

I see in `template/wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml` that there is this code block to get the level1 child categories:

```
<?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
            <li class="level0 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                <a  class="level0" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>">
                    <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
                </a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $category->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->getHierarchical()): ?>
                    <?php $children = $children = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($children) > 0): ?>
                        <ul class="level1">
                            <?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
                                <?php if ($child->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                                <li class="level1 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                    &raquo; <a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to display more than two levels of wordpress categories on Magento with Fishpig?

Answer (score 1):

I updated `template/wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml` to include a 3rd level and it worked :)

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <li class="level0 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
        <a  class="level0" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>">
            <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
        </a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $category->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getHierarchical()): ?>
            <?php $children = $children = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($children) > 0): ?>
                <ul class="level1">
                    <?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
                        <?php if ($child->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                        <li class="level1 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                            &raquo; <a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                      <?php $children2 = $children2 = $child->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                      <?php if (count($children2) > 0): ?>
                                          <ul class="level2">
                                              <?php foreach($children2 as $child2): ?>
                                                  <?php if ($child2->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                                                      <li class="level12 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child2)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                                          &raquo; <a href="<?php echo $child2->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child2->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child2->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child2->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                                      </li>
                                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                              <?php endforeach; ?>
                                          </ul>
                                      <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```